# I can't find Boars!

Tags: far-cry-3

Okay, so apart from the first mission where I had to kill 2 Boars near the area where the Komodo Dragons are found, I haven't found any more Boars thereafter. I've searched very very hard using even those hunter syringes but I can't find them. I can find pigs everywhere.

What's more is that during the first chapter, right after I activate the first radar, Dennis asks me to open the Map and I see the Boar symbol *exactly to the Komodo Dragon symbol*. But it wasn't so after the mission got over.

Right now, I must do the 3rd mission of going to speak to some Doctor who is near another corner of the island and I haven't found another boar.

Another interesting bit is that I thought this happened after patching the game to v1.02 and that's why I re-installed the game and played without patching it, but it turns that the patch had no effect on the boars whatsoever.

Is it so, that Boars shall appear again after I finish a story mission?

Please help and also it would be of immense help if someone could really post the **Boar** and the **Pig** symbol as the map legend is of little avail.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason you aren't finding any boars is because there are very few areas where they are common. For example I've unlocked 8 Radio Towers and have only opened up one area that has them.

Here is the the best screenshot I could take that should allow you to figure out how to get to the boars. Also pointed out what a pig is so you know the difference.

<sup>Click on image below to view the larger, original size image.</sup>
[image]

also here is a close up of a boar and pig

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. Please tell me what is written in **right arrow** pointing at Amanaki Town? Can't read that clearly. So this finally means that wayyy in the south is where I can find a boar? Damn. I need to upgrade my Ammo pouch which requires 2 boar hides. Have you upgraded yours?

Comment: The right arrow is Amanaki Town, also keep in mind that you could craft some of those hunter instinct syringes in order to see exactly where the boar is, if you ever lose sight of it.

Comment: Yes I've upgraded all mine, that is the fastes spot to get too from the starting town

Comment: @Paralytic - Which is the fastest spot to get too from the starting town?

Comment: The one I'm showing u in this answer amanaki town is the starting town

Comment: Yes, but after the first mission, I can't find boars from Amanaki!

Comment: @AbhishekSha Yeah i had the same one, the fastest one is indeed the one to the south. I went there on foot taking every radio tower and enemy base i could find.

Comment: I also found boars just north of Dr. Earnhardt's mansion.

Answer (score 2):

## Where can I find boars not too far from the starting zone?

As mentioned by PhysicalEd [in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96206/i-cant-find-boars#comment237714_96211), there are boars just **north of Dr Earnhardt's mansion**.
If you use the ziplines near the mansion you'll see them.
In fact, you'll probably see them during the "Mushrooms in the Deep" story mission.

There are 4 boars there. They do not respawn, but you will have enough boar hides after skinning them (assuming you didn't sell or discard any of them):

- During the "Harvest the Jungle" story mission, you have to skin 2 boars, and then use both hides to craft the "Simple Rucksack".
- You also need 2 boar hides to craft the "Simple Ammo Pouch"
- Finally, you need 2 boar hides to craft the "Rugged Fuel Sling"

As for the difference between the boar symbol and the pig symbol on the map, basically the pig is the one that looks to the right, while the boar looks to the left.